# Why am i getting menu type mismatch? It says it received menu? when it expected menu

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Im getting 2 errors on this code which wont let it run

Im not sure what is going on with the menu or why there is a type mismatch. Also im getting an error with the override. Im a little lost and any guidance is appreciated

[Here is a image of the code with the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU6lN.png)

Comment: `Menu?` means it can be `null`, `Menu` means it cannot. You should add a `null` check.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code ,it says you `onCreateOptionsMenu` overrides nothing.
Because function in parent has `onCreateOptionsMenu` function with non nullable menu `(menu:Menu?)` in argument.
So you can make menu as non null. It will also resolve when you call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu`. Because it will call super with non-null value

```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {  //Here menu is non-null
        val menuInflater = menuInflater 
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_file, menu)  
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```